# How can i delete directories including their contents using perl?

Tags: perl

It is possible to delete few directories including their contents at once using perl ?
Eg:- I have below folders

- test1
- test2
- test3
- test4

Can i delete them like rm -rf test* ?
i tried with below

```
system(@rm, '-fr', "$path/test*");
```

but its not taking `*`

Comment: This usage of `system` is a little odd; why `@rm`, is that an array with a single element in it, and that element is the string `'rm'`? Why?  But as to why the `"$path/test*"` isn't working as intended is because you are explicitly calling `system` with a list of parameters. Since there's a list, you invoke the behavior wherein the list elements are NOT checked for metacharacters, and the shell is not invoked. Without the shell getting involved, the asterisk is not expanded, but is treated as a literal part of the path. Of course switching to single-arg version of `system` would be less secure

Comment: Another consideration is how the files and directories got there in the first place, and why. If these files and directories were placed there with the intent of being temporary, living only during the runtime of the thing that put them there, then use a tempdir instead using the core module `File::Temp` to create a temporary directory under the system's $TMPDIR (typically /tmp for Linux) that gets cleaned up when it falls out of scope in the program.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I must first say that this is inherently dangerous, recursively removing directories out of a program.

Having said that, one module that provides the capability is the core [File::Path](https://perldoc.perl.org/File/Path.html)

```
use File::Path qw(remove_tree);

...

remove_tree( @dirs_to_delete, safe => 1 );
```

This will `croak` on errors, which is a pretty good idea in my opinion if recursive removal had trouble.  But if that won't work with your designs you can use the `error` option and then it's up to you to check for errors. See [Error Handling](https://perldoc.perl.org/File/Path.html#ERROR-HANDLING), and see a few other useful options.

This removes files as well. So be careful in composing the list of things to blow away, for example

```
use File::Glob ':bsd_glob';

my @dirs_to_delete = glob "$path/test*/";   # note the trailing /
```

where the trailing `/` makes it so that only directories are returned.  With [File::Glob](https://perldoc.perl.org/File/Glob.html) use statement we get the `glob` from `:bsd_glob` which works with filenames that have spaces.<sup>†</sup>  Or of course add an explicit filter with a [-d filetest](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X), `grep { -d } glob "$path/test*";`

It may also be safer to first get "closer" to what you want to remove

```
my $orig_cwd = Cwd::cwd;

chdir $path  or die "Can't \"chdir $path\": $!";

my @dirs_to_delete = glob "test*/";

# chdir $orig_cwd;
```

(there are options other than `Cwd` for `chdir`-ing and getting back to the original `cwd`)
This of course does not (at all) make it error-proof.

Please excuse repeated warnings but posting on recursive removal makes me a little nervous.

---

<sup>†</sup> Or double those (double) quotes, `glob qq{"$path/test*/"}`, or use the `\Q` form of [quotemeta](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html), `glob "\Q$path/test/*/"`, but which also escapes all non-word characters.

Comment: so @dirs_to_delete in here do i have to mention one by one ?

Comment: @Debugger  Yes, you can spell out a list (`"d1", "d2"` ... or `$d1, $d2, ...`), or you can have an array with elements which are directory names.  Please always check carefully how you generate those names in your program! (Or, you can have some code that returns a list, but that can be really dangerous.)

Comment: hmm but i need a way to delete d* without listing d1 ,d2. if i explain more i wanna delete all directories starting with d.. is it possible ?

Comment: @Debugger  That's what I meant by putting an array there, that you can populate it with names as suitable. Like `@dirs_to_delete =  glob "d*";` or such.  (_This is just an example which  assumes that `d*` are really directories to delete!_)